# Name for two columns of a table are flush towards each other, ragged on the outside?

Tags: typography, page-layout

```
    Marty  An affable Golden Retriever.
   Citrus  A sly feline with short hair.
 Lazy Sue  A feline used to being take care of.
      Bob  An imaginary pit bull.
```

Is there a name for this style where the text on the left is flush right, ragged left and the text on the right is flush right ragged left? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you pretty much described it. "Flush right / flush left" or "ragged left-ragged right." 
I can't think of a formal term that I've heard in years of layout and design work. It's kind of the reverse of a cast list in a playbill, or a table of contents, which of course usually has leaders between the left and right columns.

Central gutter? Christmas tree? Bilaterally symmetrical two-column table?

Comment: I like "Christmas tree"...